# I'm pulling a dictionary from an API call, when I pull URL information it quotes and brackets around them

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm pulling the website information using a call in my Django template.  All the information is getting pulled, but when I pull the website it has quotes and brackets around it like '[https://xxxxx.org]' obviously when I create the `<a href=>{{ web.site }}</a>` tag around it, it can't browse to the site.

Is there a quick way to strip off all the extra '[]' around the URL?

Comment: I see you properly solved the issue by yourself (congratulations) - just note that if you had posted a proper [mcve] right from the start, you may have got valid answers ;-)

Comment: Yes, I realize that it was my fault in how I proposed the issue.  I didn't know what the issue actually was until I separated all the dictionary elements.

Comment: I guess it's where experience comes into play - now you now that when you see those braces, chances are you have a list, and that a proper [mcve] is important when asking for help ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, those were all good ideas, but what was happening was I was pulling from a dictionary with an embedded list.

```
'data': {
    'BTC': {
        'urls': {
            'website': ['https://bitcoin.org/'], 
            'technical_doc': ['https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf'], 
            'twitter': [], 
            'source_code': ['https://github.com/bitcoin/']}, 
        'logo': 'https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png', 
        'id': 1, 
        'name': 'Bitcoin', 
        'symbol': 'BTC',
```

I was only accessing up to the dictionary item:

```
{{ data.BTC.urls.technical_doc }}
```

Which was returning the list:

```
['https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf']
```

To get the item I wanted inside the list, I had to add a "0" at the end to snatch out that list item:

```
{{ data.BTC.urls.technical_doc.0 }}
```

Which in turn pulled the item out of the list clean.

```
https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf
```

Thanks for everyone's help, but it was my own misunderstanding.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to make clear to anyone reading this topic what the real issue was and how to properly address it.

Comment: I tried, but evidently there is a time limit on how soon you can accept your own answer, I still have 9 hours to wait.  I'll accept it as soon as they let me.

Answer (score -1):

i think this is what you need:
[string.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip)

```
string = "'[https://xxxxx.org]'"
# strip: Remove specific characters at the beginning and at the end of the string
print(string.strip("'[]"))
# Output: https://xxxxx.org
```

Comment: Yea, I'm familiar with that, but I was hoping to strip it out in my Django Template, not in the views.py.

Comment: Addressing the symptom instead of the root issue is a sure way to end up with a complete unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers all I did was answer the question? "**Is there a quick way to strip off all the extra '[]' around the URL?**"

Comment: @Lukas cf my answer (which should have been a comment but it didn't fit...).